# Where to find Wordpress API documentation?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been looking all over but I can't find the documentation of Wordpress's XML-RPC API including a listing of all the functions, their parameters, etc. Can someone post the link(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [**this**](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp) any good?

It doesn't look like a lot but it seems to be the official documentation. I don't think it's going to get any better than that, except maybe for 3rd party tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for "Wordpress XML-RPC API documentation" points to [this site](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support), which seems to be the official documantation. It contains links to all the supported general blogging APIs as well as special Wordpress extensions and general development information.

Comment: @Chacha102: Slightly different and much more comprehensive link, IMHO